# Sharepoint 2010 Client Object Model - windows authentication - credentials of logged on user

Tags: com, sharepoint-2010, windows-authentication, networkcredentials

In a SharePoint application page I have to get listitems from a list on remote server in the same Active Directory domain.
I use the Client Object Model to get at the list.  If I do not supply Network credentials (with userid, password and domain) I get a 401 access denied.

Is there a way to pass the credentials of the user that is logged in in Sharepoint (not in the windows client; can be different) to the ClientContext to allow it to get at the remote list?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Sharepoint2010 Web Application is configured with Claims based authentication. It needs to be configured with Classic Authentication so that you will not have to pass the username and password explicitly.